# Matplotlib basemap reading shapefile is very slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a simple 'merc' map with boundary from shape file. The total size of the shape file `ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp` is just 8mb. The simple mslp surface plot from GFS data took about more than 28 sec which I think is too much. After investigation I found that it is the reading of shape file consuming around 10 sec. A simple code to demonstrate the issue is shown below:-

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


south = 0
north = 5
west = 70
east = 85

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
        llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, resolution='c')
m.readshapefile('data/gis-data/world_countries/'
    'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes', 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes', linewidth=0.7)

plt.savefig('map.png')
```

To show the problem I am facing, I have run the above code with and without commenting the path to shape file. Here is time the script took after reading from shape file:-

```
$ time python test.py 
real    0m18.234s
user    0m17.832s
sys 0m1.020s
```

Here is the result without reading from shape file:-

```
$ time python test.py 
real    0m2.506s
user    0m2.360s
sys 0m0.324s
```

Is there any way to read the shape file quickly? Is there any solution/trick  for this issue?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/180451/115

Answer (score 0):

I would put this question into Geographic Information Systems too, there are some people to help you. If basemap is slow, did you try cartopy, i saw this on the matplotlib site, see http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/mpl_toolkits/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem here is not the `basemap`. It is the reading of shapefile. I have read some of the custom shape file. Some where I read that `pickle` should improve the plotting speed. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: But isn't it m = Basemap so a Basemap-instance reads your shapefile?

Comment: It is able to read the shapefile. But it is very slow. There are 100 of images I have to generate and it takes lot of time to plot.